# Digitalocean managed DB [could not create SSL context: library has no ciphers]

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, digital-ocean

Recently I have purchased Managed Database service from digital ocean.

My app is developed in Flask. It works from local but when run with wsgi apache it shows this (apache2) error :

```
(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not create SSL context: library has no ciphers
```

By defalut sslmode=require from their server. I can't connect the database using uwsgi mode.
this is the connection string:

```
 "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI": "postgres://myuser:password@0000.db.ondigitalocean.com:2000/database?sslmode=require"
```

Comment: So what ciphers do you actually have on your application server? How did you check this?

Comment: the report is from apache error log. I have installed letsencrypt as a domain ssl. Do I need any other certificate ?

Comment: The error is clearly to do with your python postgresql library, rather than apache.

Comment: I am also thinking that.